# Merge array1 and array 2 values into array3 objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a problem regrading merging of multiple array values into single array. Following are the arrays:

```
array1
(

{
    Id = 10166;
    Name = "Paul";
},
{
    Id = 10167;
    Name = "Dipleep";
},
{
    Id = 10168;
    Name = "John";

}
 )

array 2
(
{

    Country = USA;
},
{

    Country = India;
},
{

    Country = USA;

}
)

array3

(
{
    Id = 10166;
    Name = "Paul";
    Country = USA;
},
{
    Id = 10167;
    Name = "Dipleep";
    Country = India;
},
{
    Id = 10168;
    Name = "John";
    Country = USA;

}
)
```

I have no idea how to do but tried a bit like:

```
NSMutableArray *newArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[newArr addObjectsFromArray:cartArray];
[newArr addObjectsFromArray:couponsArray];
```

But adding it wrongly. Could you please find me the solution for combining multiple array values into another array. TIA

Comment: " But adding it wrongly ".... I didn't get it. Could you explain the issue ?

Comment: "into array3", you mean that you want to use array1 and array2 to create array3 right? Just do a for loop and create a new dict with each values.

Comment: yes @Larme. Could your please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {


    NSString *idOfObj = [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Id"];
    NSString *name = [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *country = [[array2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Country"];

    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"Id" :idOfObj,@"Name" : name,@"Country" : country};

    [array3 addObject:dic];
}

NSLog(@"result array : %@",array3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a simple task:
You iterate, create a new dictionary combining the values from the object in `array1` and in `array2` at the same index.

```
NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array1 count]; i ++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [tempDict addEntriesFromDictionary:array1[i]];
    [tempDict addEntriesFromDictionary:array2[i]];
    [array3 addObject:tempDict];
}
```

As simple as it may be, there are still some issues that you could have and could cause a crash. You may not fall into these cases, but another user that have the same question could.

So now, what you need to think about:
• What if `array1[n]` keys has a common key with `array2[n]`? Because keys in dictionaries are unique. So the value will be replaced (check the doc of `addEntriesFromDictionary:`)
• What if `[array1 count]` is different from `[array2 count]`? Yeah the `for loop` may crash due to an out of bounds issue.
• Why is your data separated like this at the beginning? You are trying to "resynchronize" them, that's good, but are you sure that they are correctly synchronized? I mean, that `array1[n]` values really correspond to `array2[n]` and not `array2[m]` values? Especially if you are getting them asynchronously...